# sending multiple variables in url for php with jquery ajax post call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

am trying to send this data to php page for insert it in my database

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"ajax/sale-your-car.php",
    data:"makes="+makes+"&model="+model+"&style="+style+"&price="+price+"&ExteriorColor="+ExteriorColor+"&year="+year+"&transmission="+transmission+"&mileage="+mileage,
    success:function(data){
        $("#ie").html(data);
    }
});
```

but it dose not work i there limit for sending this data

Comment: You're complicating it, just do `data : {makes : makes, model : model ...}` etc instead.

Comment: i try to send 7  variable : value as you said :( but it stop working

Comment: If you send it via POST, and set the data as @adeneo said, make sure your PHP script is reading from the `$_POST` variable

Answer (score 0):

Can you try sending the data in the following form:

```
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

This format is mentioned in the [Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

I would alert those variables to make sure they have values just to double-check as well.